# Twilio Salesforce Integration for calls and transcribe

Tags: api, salesforce, integration, apex, twilio-api

First I'd like to say I'm a beginner developer and this is my first real life project. And I'm stuck.

I need to integrate Twilio with Salesforce and be able to get inbound and make outbound calls from Salesforce and transcribe those calls. Also the receive and send messages option would be useful.

I made some research and there's only a deprecated Twilio library for Salesforce. Twilio offers a lot of documentation, but for other programming languages, not for Apex.

If someone could give me some ideas on how to write the code I need, that would be great! I'm really lost.

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Ernesto Pastura

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sounds like you were given a rather large complex first project.  There is a AppExchange package, and you probably want to see if that meets your needs before implementing something custom: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EtEuBUAV.   StackOverflow will be most useful to you when you can get far enough to have specific problems with specific code. General guidance on how to write code isn't really what this community was built to provide.

Comment: This entire solution is available out of the box: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/integrations/salesforce

Comment: @identigral Thank you so much for the info!! I am totally new to Twilio and just starting my developer career with Salesforce. Do you know how can I make the transcribe functionality work. Using Flex, I already made a call from Salesforce, but couldn't find the transcribe documentation. Thank you so much!!! Your comment was a great help!

Comment: @acrosman thanks for your answer, but that package only allows me to send and receive messages. I'm looking for a way to make a receive calls in Salesforce and also transcribe those calls. Any ideas are welcome!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi @ErnestoPastura, I don't know if you ever figured this out, but my company has done this for multiple customers as a Salesforce and Twilio Consulting partner. I would recommend looking at the VoiceBase addon for Twilio in this case for transcription. Feel free to check out https://visionpoint.systems for more tips.